# ? redirect()->away('http://mirulexterna') no funciona en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

buenos días tengo el sigueinte controller en `Auth\ResetPasswordController`

```
class ResetPasswordController 
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/http://miurlexterna';

    public function show(string $token)
    {
        return view('auth.reset-password', [
            'token' => $token
        ]);
    }
  
    public function handle()
    {
        request()->validate([
            'token' => ['required', 'string'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed']
        ]);

        $status = Password::reset(
            request(['email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token']),
            function ($user, $password) {
                $user->update(['password' => Hash::make($password)]);
                $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
            }
        );
    
        return $status === Password::PASSWORD_RESET
             
            ? redirect()->away('http://miurlexterna')
            : back()->withErrors(['email' => 'EL token es invalido.']);
    }
}
```

Pero no redirecciona a la url externa eso lo invoco cuando deseo hacer cambio de contraseña quiero que si el `$estatus === Password::PASSWORD_RESET`, el sistema redirija a otra url externa alguien me puede orientar? llevo días en esto y no doy con el problema.

Actualmente al realizar cambio de contraseña me dirige al login del proyecto laravel en donde está esa clase `ResetPasswordController`, pero yo no quiero ir al login quiero que se vaya a la url externa, les doy las gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan proporcionar

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes si se cumple esa condición `$status === Password::PASSWORD_RESET`? ¿Que pasa si haces directamente `return redirect()->away('http://miurlexterna');`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ no entra alli si hago un return redirec directo no entra. No tengo idea donde debo modificar, porque si cometo un error a propósito en esa linea me dice que tengo un error cuando hago password reset , pero me redirige al login con un mensaje status que tampoco estoy configurando es como si el método no fuera ese